# 2-stage BJT amplifier for low impedance load

Tags: amplifier, bjt

I need to design a 2 stage bjt amplifier that would amplify a 0.1uV waveform at least 100 times on a 4ohm load. How do I choose the proper stages for amplification? I was thinking about the most common CE-CC amplifier but I'm not sure if that's the best choice
[image: Amplifier]

UPD: I made the 1st stage (CE) to have a gain of a little more than 100 but measured at 22kOhm load, Is that good enough to use with the CC amplifier?

[image: CE]
[image: CE output]

Comment: CC is good choice for the 4 ohm load.  Single stage CE with ac gain of 100 isn't unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzJ3OD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That 0.1uv (100 nanoVolt) input will be amplified 200X in Q1, then attenuated 2:1 by the voltage-divider of Q2's Rout and the 4 ohm load.

Assuming zero-source impedance, so Miller Effect has no effect on bandwidth, your gain-node time-constant will be 20pF * 200 ohm or 4,000 nanoseconds, thus bandwidth will be about 40MHz. Amazing.

Assuming the dominant random-noise contributor is rbb' of Q1, at 62 ohms, the noise density of 62 ohms is exactly 1 nanoVolt/rootHertz. A bandwidth of 40MHz increases the noise by 1nanoVolt * sqrt(40,000,000) = 1nV * 6,500 = 6.5 uV RMS
referred-to-input random noise. The output noise, loaded by 4 ohms, will be 100X higher at 1.3 milliVolts RMS, about 9 milliVolts 6 sigma (2 ppm).

Your mileage may vary. I used no simulator in designing this.

Comment: So whats the point of C5 capacitor? The amplifiers we designed are usually biased with a simple two resistor voltage divider, so your biasing configuration confuses me a little

Comment: The shown bias network is a very good one - it provides DC feedback for ensuring a stable bias point. It is the task of the capacitor C5 to allow only DC feedback. Frequencies above the corresponding corner frequency do not reach the base and, thus, cannot provide signal feedback with gain reduction.

Comment: @LvW The lower corner is 0.16Hz * Av = 200 (or 32Hz). Is this easy to prove?

Comment: The cap value is 1 milliF. hence, the time constant is app. 1E-3*1E3=1 sec. That means wo=1rad/sec and fo=wo/6.28